# IOS - Remote control events aren't received when a modal view is on top of the main view

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I have an app that plays audio in the background.  Everything works fine when the main view is the view that the user was last on.

However, if the user goes to a second view, then the remote control events no longer work.

The main view controller is where I handle the remote control events.  What should I do so that the remote controls can control the audio of the app, even if the main view is not in focus?

UPDATE:

Adding this code to my main view controller seems to make everything work fine.

```
- (BOOL)canResignFirstResponder{
    return NO;
}
```

Could having that code have any bad side effects?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have two different view controllers, one for the main view and one for the modal view.  It might be cleaner to have the main view controller set 'canBecomeFirstResponder' to YES and the sub controller set 'canBecomeFirstResponder' to NO.  There should be no ill side affects from your code as long as you remember to call make sure to resign it when the app exits.

Either with:

```
- (BOOL)canResignFirstResponder{
    return mAppIsActive;
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    mAppIsActive = false;
}
```

or

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{   
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self.viewController resignFirstResponder];
}
```